# python json format error , "TypeError: string indices must be integers"

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, parsing

My question is about an error while json parsing in python3. I am getting error `TypeError: string indices must be integers`. From zeroMQ, data is being received. The console output section is below.

```py
message = socket.recv()
 
print("DBG#80:orginal message:", message)
message_string = message.decode("utf-8")  # VVI important (it removes b" \" etc ")
print("DBG#81:message.decode('utf-8'):", message_string)
  
correlation_id_rcvd = json.dumps(message_string,separators=(',', ':'))
print("DBG#82:parsed json full=", correlation_id_rcvd)
print("DBG#83:message_correlation_id=" ,correlation_id_rcvd["message_correlation_id"])
```

console output

```
DBG#80:orginal message: b"{'payload':{'msg_id':'0','message_correlation_id':'9f1911c2-9f3c-11eb-91f7-acde48001122', 'msg':'Random_msg_RDnxThkXqH'}}"
DBG#81:message.decode('utf-8'): {'payload':{'msg_id':'0','message_correlation_id':'9f1911c2-9f3c-11eb-91f7-acde48001122', 'msg':'Random_msg_RDnxThkXqH'}}
DBG#82:parsed json full= "{'payload':{'msg_id':'0','message_correlation_id':'9f1911c2-9f3c-11eb-91f7-acde48001122', 'msg':'Random_msg_RDnxThkXqH'}}"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "zeromq_pub_5.py", line 122, in <module>
    print("DBG#83:message_correlation_id=" ,correlation_id_rcvd["message_correlation_id"])
**TypeError: string indices must be integers**
```

Comment: `json.dumps` doesn’t ***parse*** JSON; that also isn’t valid JSON. Looks like a stringified Python dict. If you intend to send JSON, you should first of all ensure you’re actually doing that.

Comment: Use `json.loads` to decode string JSON to python object (list or dict). `json.parse` does the exact opposite, which isn’t what you want. https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: i am VERY new to python: How do I access a JSON elements value from ,a simple example gives error
>> 
msg_debug={"payload": {"message_correlation_id":"dee4aee8-9f36-11eb-a1ee-acde48001122","rcvd_msg":{"msg":"Random_msg_gJwURRUGVU"}}}
correlation_id_rcvd=json.dumps(msg_debug,separators=(',', ':'))
print(correlation_id_rcvd["message_correlation_id"])
TypeError: string indices must be integers